# FPDF PHP MYSQL Text Does Not Fit In Cell

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, fpdf

I want to export data from MySql database in pdf format. I can do this from within the mysql database, it's very nice. I tried to automate this. I used the FPDF library but the data does not fit into the tables. I searched but couldn't fix it.

What should I do ?

Images :

My Columns :

[image: Columns]

Sample Content :
[image: content]

My Code :

```
<?php
 require('./fpdf/fpdf.php');

//Database 
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_config.php';
$connection = 
mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);

if(!$connection){
    die("Connection error  : " . mysqli_connect_eror());
}

class PDF extends FPDF
 {
    // Page header
    function Header()
    {
        $ImagePath ='image url';
        // Logo
        $this->Image($ImagePath,10,70,0,90);
        $this->SetFont('Arial','B',13);
        // Move to the right
        $this->Cell(80);
        // Title
        $this->Cell(80,10,'title',1,0,'C');
        // Line break
        $this->Ln(20);
    }
     
    // Page footer
    function Footer()
    {
        // Position at 1.5 cm from bottom
        $this->SetY(-15);
        // Arial italic 8
        $this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
        // Page number
        $this->Cell(0,10,'Page '.$this- 
    >PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C');
    }
    
 }
 // Columns 
    $display_heading = array('JobId'=>'JobId','ReleaseDate'=> 
'ReleaseDate', 
'StartingDate'=> 
'StartingDate','TargetTime'=>'TargetTime','JobContent'=> 

     'JobContent','KindId'=>'KindId','JobStatus'=>'JobStatus','CustomerId'  
=>'CustomerId');
    
 // Database Result    
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM Jobs;") or die("database 
 error:". mysqli_error($connection));
    $header = mysqli_query($connection, "SHOW columns FROM Jobs");
    
    // Settings
    $pdf = new PDF();
    //header
    $pdf->AddPage();
    //foter page
    $pdf->AliasNbPages();
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',8);
    foreach($header as $heading) {
    $pdf->Cell(24,7,$display_heading[$heading['Field']],1);
    }
    foreach($result as $row) {
    $pdf->Ln();
    foreach($row as $column)
    $pdf->Cell(24,7,$column,1);
    
    }
    $pdf->Output();

 //Connection close
 mysqli_close($connection);

 ?>
```

Comment: Consider using the script [Table with MultiCells](http://www.fpdf.org/?go=script&id=3).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GetStringWidth()` to determine how many mm wide a given string in the current font configuration is. Based on that, you can decrease the font size or insert line breaks, if the string width is wider than you threshold (in your case the cell width).

```
$fontSize = 14;
while($pdf->GetStringWidth($text) > 80){
    $pdf->setFontSize(--$fontSize);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the "Fix text to cell" extension at http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script62.php. See the resulting example PDF at http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/ex62.pdf to see what it looks like.

If you don't want to compress the text like that, something along the lines of what @stui has suggested would likely work best (getting the string width, and splitting the text across multiple lines).